# Auto disconnect from WLAN if unused

Tags: power-management, wlan

For Nokia N900 there is an app called AutoDisconnect which monitors the WLAN usage and closes the connection if the traffic is very low.

I'd like to have something like this on my future notebook in order to save battery life, i.e. to auto disable WLAN when not needed. Is there any solution to achieve this in Linux? I'm planning to use Linux Mint as the distro of my choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some bandwidth monitoring tool, such as `vnstat`, for this. To install it on Linux Mint, do:

```
sudo apt-get install vnstat
```

Then, you can monitor the average speed of your connection over some specified time, and if the speed comes out to be lower than some specific limit, then turn off your WLAN.

So, let's say you want to switch off your WLAN if your average download rate falls below `5 KB/s` over a monitoring time of 30 seconds, then your code would be:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Taking sudo power initially because it will be required later on
sudo echo "Starting AutoDisconnect"

while true
do
  downSpeed=$(vnstat -ru 0 -tr 30 -i wlan0 | grep rx | grep -oP "\d+\.\d+")
  if (( $(echo "$downSpeed < 5.0" | bc -l) ))
  then
    sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
    exit  #exit now because we don't need monitoring since the interface is down
  fi
done
```

#### Explanation of important bits

```
-ru 0      ==> to show the rate in bytes/s (use "1" for bits/s)
-tr 30     ==> take average over 30 seconds usage
-i wlan0   ==> `vnstat` defaults to eth0 on my computer (marmistrz)
bc -l      ==> used in bash for doing arithmetic

grep rx             ==> considering only the receiving rate (i.e. download rate)
grep -oP "\d+\.\d+" ==> strip out the download rate from the output
```